# Divorce, Talaaq, Marriage

Tags: talaq

My husband shouted at me Talaaq two times while he was angry. After some time, around six months, he texted me again stating in writing over chat in WhatsApp that henceforth we are to be considered Talaaq, not husband and wife anymore. Is our Nikah annulled?

Comment: We do not give legal verdicts, consult a Mufti with the details of your case. From the sparse detail given in the post it seems obvious that the nikah is over as the husband has given divorce.